# How to calculate the angle for the phasor form?

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism, homework

**I have the following problem:**

> A one-phase voltage of `v(t) = 150⋅sin(wt)`
> is connected to a load with impedance `Z=2+4j Ohm`.
> What is the current through the load, on phasor form? (use the supply voltage as reference)

**My problem:**
I think the magnitude is 23.7  (taking 150/sqrt(2) and dividing by 4.47 since r=sqrt(2^2 + 4^2).  But how do i calculate the angle for the phasor form?

Comment: It is usually good practice to write “rms” out beside rms quantities too.  Avoids assumption errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the magnitude of the current is 23.72 amps.

To calculate the phase angle, the easiest way is to convert the rectangular impedance to a magnitude (already done) and an angle. The angle is \$\arctan(4/2)\$ = 63.435 °.

Given that it is a positive value, when you divide voltage (at 0 °) by an impedance having an angle of +63.435 ° the net result for current is a negative angle of 63.435 °